# Algolia display addresses for only specific country

Tags: algolia

Is it possible to limit the autocomplete options to results only from one country?

For example our website will offer delivery only within the country so searching or displaying options from outside this country will not be relevant and even cause confusion in the UX.

Comment: Could you tell us what front-end integration you're using? Are you using Algolia Places? Or is it a dropdown from a WordPress or Magento integration? Or directly using the autocomplete.js library?

Comment: Yes using places: https://github.com/algolia/places

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the [two-letter country iso-codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Officially_assigned_code_elements) you want to restict the search on in the `countries` parameter like this:

```
var placesAutocomplete = places({
  container: document.querySelector('#your-input'),
  countries: ['gb', 'fr']
});
```

Checkout the documentation for the full list of available options:
https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#options